# How many (m)W should 120 ohm CAN bus terminators have?

Tags: resistors, can, termination

When I started with Arduino I bought a set of 600 resistors (30 times 20 values). However, I found out 120 ohm needed for CAN bus is not among them.

So I need to buy 120 ohm resistors (I don't want to combine multiple). However, I was wondering how many watts they should handle.

I want to connect two or later maybe three devices, all running on USB power (5V). But I cannot find how many (m)A CAN is using.

My calculations:

V = I * R <=> 5 = I * 120 <=> I = 5 / 120 = 41,7 mA

P = I * V = 0,041666 * 5 = 0.208W

or:

P = I^2 * R = 0.041666 0.208W

So I would be safe with default (0.25W) 120 ohm resistors?

Comment: Your assumption that there is going to be 5 V across these resistors is incorrect I believe. According to the CAN Bus page in Wikipedia the voltages are half of that so 2.5 V maximum. So then you'd be well within limits to use 0.25 W resistors assuming you'd be terminating to the 2.5 V which is the recessive ("one") voltage of the datalines.

Comment: this might help: https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/industrial_interface/f/142/t/246035

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I see there: High speed CAN signaling drives the CAN high wire towards 5 V and the CAN low wire towards 0 V when transmitting a dominant (0), and does not drive either wire when transmitting a recessive (1). The dominant differential voltage is a nominal 2 V. The termination resistor passively returns the two wires to a nominal differential voltage of 0 V. The dominant common mode voltage must be within 1.5 to 3.5 V of common and the recessive common mode voltage must be within +/-12 of common.     But I use USB so I cannot even generate 12V

Comment: Who says you need to generate 12 V ? Looking at this graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#/media/File:ISO11898-2.svg you can generate it from 5 V. That +/- 12 V of common has more to do with absolute maxima, you must be able to handle that (use input voltage protection) but no need to generate that. I think that is to make the system immune to when a broken circuit puts 12 V on the line or the car battery is connected in reverse.

Comment: @Arsenal ... I checked it ...and added the formula (which gives the same value). So I guess 0.25W is ok.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't think I need the input protection, I know exactly where I connect it to (all 5V USB powered STM32s, or maybe an Arduino, USB powered).

Comment: OK, you're not going to use it in a car and no one is going to check if you meet all the CAN Bus requirements then for sure you do not need input protection.

Comment: The resitors will have 5V across them when the bus is in the dominant state and 0 V when it is in the recessive state. Since the bus will when active spend around 50% of the time in each state it's reasonable to use a rating that is assuming half way in between the two. which gives a power of V^2/R = 50 mW.

Comment: @Andrew ... ok (I guess with 5V I'm still safe, just wondering what the rest of your sentence will be.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by accident.

Comment: @Andrew ... no problem, Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You can calculate P more directly with P = V^2/R. When V is 5 volts and R is 120 ohms, you get 25/120, which is .208.

Comment: Thanks for all comments ... I bought 120 ohm resistors, however, I saw that the TJA1050 CAN transceiver already has one present.

Comment: I've always used 0.5W as some in-house standard which I don't know the rationale for. Here is a good post about the topic though: https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/industrial_interface/f/142/t/246035

Comment: @Lundin ... thanks ... I also read that post, but I think it's (also) related to CAN busses for cars etc (12V).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I pretty much exclusively use CAN in 24V vehicle applications. Never had a problem with 0.5W even though people occasionally manage to put 24V on the CAN lines. I've seen a few fried CAN transceivers but that's very rare. I would imagine that protection diodes inside the CAN transceivers blow long before the terminator resistors exceed their specified power rating.

Comment: @Lundin I ordered JTA1050 which have those resistors probably already inside, but just in case I ordered 0,25W. Probably that will be enough since I use only 2 or max 3 5V USB powered devices and I am sure no 'unknown'  devices will be part of the network. Also at least two of them will be STM32s which work internally on 3.3V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have your answer from the comments, so this is mainly for posterity purposes.

Your calculations are correct, at a max of 5V differential voltage you would have ~42mA which would dissipate ~210mW.  **You are safe using a 0.25W resistor, especially since you know exactly what is going to be connected to the bus.**

I would like to add that I work with CAN on a regular basis, some of which can be in rather demanding environments, and our typical termination is shown below.  We use standard 0805 resistors with a rating of 0.125W and I have yet to see a burnt resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6yjYY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: (forgot to accept the answer) ... thanks for the clear scheme!

Comment: Old answer, but there is an interesting caveat here. Some CAN High Level protocols (e.g. Devicenet), or rather their additional compliance requirements, may require that any wires in the physical interface can be interchanged without causing damage. In the case where someone wires bus supply to CAN H, an explicitly tested error,  a 0.125W resistor will fail this test for example on a 24V Bus. And in that instance I have seen terminators fry :)